# GCM push different payload to different device

Tags: json, google-cloud-messaging

I will like to push different payload to differet devices at same time. Now I only able to push same payload to different devices with the code below.

```
    string stringregIds = null;

    List<string> regIDs = new List<string>();

    //Add some regID into the list

    stringregIds = string.Join("\",\"", regIDs.ToArray());;

    string applicationID = "appID"; 

    string SENDER_ID = "senderID";

    string value = "Hello";                                                                           

    WebRequest tRequest;

    tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

    tRequest.Method = "post";

    tRequest.ContentType = " application/json;charset=UTF-8";

    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

    string postData = "{\"collapse_key\":\"score_update\",\"time_to_live\":108,\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"data\": { \"message\" : "
                      +"\""+value+"\",\"time\": "+"\""+System.DateTime.Now.ToString()+"\"},\"registration_ids\":[\""+stringregIds+"\"]}";                                                                                                                                


    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();

    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

    dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

    tReader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    tResponse.Close();
```

Is there any solution to send multiple payload to multiple devices?

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for sending different payloads to different devices. You'll have to send each message in a separate HTTP request. Each request will contain a single Registration ID.